# Auction House CLI: I cannot execute the sale instruction to list my NFT

Tags: solana, metaplex

I am running the following command to list an NFT on devnet.

```
 ts-node src/auction-house-cli.ts sell \
  -k /Users/wizard/.config/solana/devnet.json \
  -ah 7sghryHrhZ48DKAt8jCtaZGcX9DioVzykwAeqQhwstKn \
  --buy-price 1 \
  --mint DJPcJZkmpazb75Eu2moXjt8dfE2sTqxeZAWH6fYEFu4Q \
  --token-size 1
```

The return output

```
wallet public key: 6SNzXuypAYyC7U41c4J6i7X5XGe9J6fG2w3iZPpoJgAV
Using cluster devnet
Rejected via websocket { InstructionError: [ 0, { Custom: 1 } ] }
Timeout Error caught {
  err: { InstructionError: [ 0, [Object] ] },
  slot: 145039789,
  confirmations: 0
}
/Users/wizard/metaplex-folder/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/transactions.ts:136
            throw new Error(
                  ^
Error: Transaction failed: Transfer 897840 lamports to the new account
    at sendSignedTransaction (/Users/wizard/metaplex-folder/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/transactions.ts:136:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async sendTransactionWithRetryWithKeypair (/Users/wizard/metaplex-folder/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/transactions.ts:59:26)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/wizard/metaplex-folder/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/auction-house-cli.ts:329:5)
```

My wallet address: **6SNzXuypAYyC7U41c4J6i7X5XGe9J6fG2w3iZPpoJgAV** has the NFT I am trying to list and the SOL to pay for the transaction. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? 

My  Auction House Fee Payer account has more than enough - 2.99 SOL. Yet I'm still getting the timeout. It's coming from Auction House CLI / `Buy` command - `sendTransactionWithRetryWithKeypair` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your Fee Account is empty and seems like you haven't yet topped it off.

You can check the amount in your Fee Account using the following command:

```
ts-node src/auction-house-cli.ts show -k <wallet_location> -ah <auction_house_key>
```

Your output will most probably show:

```
Fee Payer Bal: 0
```

You can read more about the Fee Account here: https://docs.metaplex.com/auction-house/cli#fee-account

To top it off, you could simply `airdrop` SOL to the `FeeAccount`. More precisely, you need to transfer `897840` lamports to your FeeAccount, as stated in the error message

Comment: My Fee Payer account has more than enough - 2.99 SOL. Yet I'm still getting the timeout. It's coming from Auction House CLI / Buy `sendTransactionWithRetryWithKeypair` function.